# Import error while importing bootstrapJS file in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have downloaded all the packages given below and imported in App.js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
import '@popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' // problem in this line
```

If I import bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js then it says

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'project_root\client\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
```

Even if I copy and paste popper.js file in

```
'project_root\client\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
```

It still shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Popper is a dependency required by bootstrap so you will need to install it.